# Is there a way to thicken a form legend underline?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want bootstrap legend's underline to be more thick.
I would like to override twitter bootstrap css.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
legend {
    border-bottom:10px solid #000000;
}
```

To further increase/decrease the thickness, you can increase/decrease the pixels in the `border-bottom`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. With CSS:

Bootstrap currently uses:

```
legend {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5
}
```

In order to increase the thickness, simply increase the `1px` value to something greater:

```
legend {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #E5E5E5
}
```

**[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8StUj/)**.

In order to get your own CSS to override the Bootstrap CSS, ensure your CSS is included on your page *after* Bootstrap, otherwise your style will be ignored:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="yourStylesheet.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried actually looking on the css code? It's `border-bottom` on `legend`.

```
legend {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #333333;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5; /* that's the one */
}
```